# React. How to decrease timer value in localstorage by one?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, timer, local-storage

How to decrease timer value in `localstorage` by one? I used the [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) hook, but the value does not dynamically decrease by one. Thank you!

Timer:

```
const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useLocalStorage('timer',  5 * 60)

const getPadTime = (time) => time.toString().padStart(2, '0')

const minutes = getPadTime(Math.floor(timeLeft / 60))
const seconds = getPadTime(timeLeft - minutes * 60)

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTimeLeft((timeLeft) => (timeLeft >= 1 ? timeLeft - 1 : setDisabled() ||  5 * 60))
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval) 
}, [])
```

Comment: The code works fine? https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-hodgkin-9e76q4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you, guys! Both of variants are working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use-local-storage` hook you referred to does not support the `setState(previousValue => nextValue)` syntax.

The easiest way to fix this is to use a different implementation, e.g. this one: [use-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-local-storage), used in gerrod 's comment

Comment: Thank you, guys! Both of variants are working!